# Determining the date logic based on a given string in c#

Tags: c#

I have written a logic in c# that determines the nextCallDate based on the given cobDate. cobDate is current date -1.

So if there are more than one future date in the given string then it should return the nearest future date to the cobdate and ignore the rest

For eg if the cobdate is 2020/02/12 and the string is
;2;4;2;5;20180328;3;103.3750;5;20190328;3;102.250;5; 20200328;3;101.1250;5;20210328;3;100.00;

Then  NextCallDate would be 2020/03/28.

I need to return blank for dates in the past.
So say in the example if the given string has all the dates in the past then it should return blank.
Given string ;2;1;2;5;20120918;3;100.000000;

Here is what I have written

```
 private DateTime? GetNextCallDate(string nextCallDate)
        {
            DateTime cobDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);
            var parts = nextCallDate.Split(';');
            

            foreach (var part in parts)
            {
                DateTime parsedNextCallDate = DateTime.Parse(part);
                if (parsedNextCallDate.Date > cobDate.Date)
                {
                    return parsedNextCallDate;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: What is your function returning?

Comment: it is returning date

Comment: What do you mean by "blank"? Do you mean `null`?

Comment: You should proabaly be using `DateTime.TryParse` instead of `Parse`, since some of the values are not dates. Also, it looks like you're returning the first date that's greater than `cobDate`, not the nearest one.

Comment: I meant need to return null

Comment: @RufusL your observation seems right. How do I handle that

Comment: I added an example as an answer. It works on my machine, but you would have to test it with your actual data to make sure it works. The one thing I could envision is if you have any different formats, such as dates with a single-character day or month, then we'd need to add some more patterns to `TryParseExact`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using `DateTime.TryParse` instead of `Parse`, since some of the values are not dates. Also, it looks like you're returning the first date that's greater than cobDate, not the nearest one.

To resolve this, we first set `parsedNextCallDate` to `null`, and this will be our default return value. Then we can check each part if it's a `DateTime` using the return value from `TryParse`, and then compare the value to both `cobDate` and `parsedNextCallDate`. If the date is greater than `cobDate` and less than `parasedNextCallDate` (or if `parasedNextCallDate` isn't set yet), then we update `parasedNextCallDate` to the new value. At the end, we just return `parasedNextCallDate`:

```
public static DateTime? GetNextCallDate(string input)
{
    DateTime? nextCallDate = null;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return nextCallDate;

    var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    var inputItems = input.Split(';');

    foreach (var inputItem in inputItems)
    {
        DateTime itemDate;

        // If inputItem is a DateTime and it's greater than yesterday
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputItem.Trim(), "yyyyMMdd", null, 
            DateTimeStyles.None, out itemDate) &&
            itemDate.Date > yesterday)
        {
            // and if nextCallDate doesn't have a value or the parsed value
            // is less than nextCallDate, assign nextCallDate to this value
            if (!nextCallDate.HasValue || itemDate < nextCallDate)
            {
                nextCallDate = itemDate;
            }
        }
    }

    return nextCallDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way solve your problem.  Breaking things down into steps often makes things easier to reason with and easier to test.  I'm often working on server side apps so I like the new span/memory classes.  So first thing is to split our input string into chunks:

```
    static IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> ReduceToPossibleDates(string source)
    {
        const int ExpectedDateLen = 9; // includes separator

        int last = 0;
        var mem = source.AsMemory();
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (';' == mem.Span[i])
            {
                int length = i - last;

                if (length == ExpectedDateLen)
                {
                    yield return mem.Slice(last+1,length-1);
                }

                last = i;
            }
        }
    }
```

This gives us a stream of ReadOnlyMemory that all contains what we think should be dates.  Next we can do another method to consume those chunks and turn them into dates.

```
    static IEnumerable<DateTime> ToDateTime(IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> rawDates)
    {
        foreach (var rawDate in rawDates)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(rawDate.Span,"yyyyMMdd".AsSpan(), 
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                            DateTimeStyles.None, out var date))
                yield return date;
        }
    }
```

Once we have that we can treat the stream of dates however we want.  In this case we check to find the first that's after our COB.

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        const string GoodData = ";2;4;2;5;20180328;3;103.3750;5;20190328;3;102.250;"+
                                 "5;20200328;3;101.1250;5;20210328;3;100.00;";
        const string NoDateData = ";2;1;2;5;20120918;3;100.000000;";

        var cobDate = new DateTime(2020, 2,12); // some actual close of business date...

        var nextCallDate = ToDateTime(ReduceToPossibleDates(GoodData))
                                .FirstOrDefault(x => x >= cobDate);
        var noDateExpected = ToDateTime(ReduceToPossibleDates(NoDateData))
                                .FirstOrDefault(x => x >= cobDate);

        if (nextCallDate != default(DateTime))
            Console.WriteLine(nextCallDate);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("no call date.");

        if (noDateExpected != default(DateTime))
            Console.WriteLine(nextCallDate);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("no call date.");
    }
```

It would be a little cleaner with extension methods but you get the idea.